# Angular - Delaying forEach

Tags: angularjs, animation, foreach

I have a problem. I am trying to create an animation, changing the color of several layers with a timeout between painted.

```
$scope.StartMovementsAnimation = function()
{
      angular.forEach($scope.GameMovements, function(movement){
       if (movement == "Green")
       {
          $scope.Green = true;
       }
       else (movement == "Orange")
       {
          $scope.Orange = true;
       } 
  });
}
```

The problem I have is that I do not know how to stop or delay the flow loop. I'm pretty lost. I tried with $ timeout, sleep etc but does not work.

Any solution?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use forEach. Use $timeout to repeat as many as the number of items in your GameMovements array.

Take a look at the following example. It is going to change `className` field from orange to green and vice versa till the variable `left`'s value reaches 0.

```
$scope.className = "orange";
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.startAnimation = function() {
  var left = 10
  var ticker = function() {
    if (left % 2 === 0)
      $scope.className = 'orange'
    else
      $scope.className = 'green'
    left -= 1
    if (left > 0) {
      $timeout(ticker, 1000)
    }
  }

  $timeout(ticker, 1000)
}
```